# Cosmos db querying single item with hierarchical partition keys using point read

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a setup where the partition key is the phone number of the user and hierarchical partition key is 'user'. Querying using the select statement below would get me the single record I am looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM c Where c.pk='14160000000' AND c.hpk='user'
```

I want to know if it is possible to get the same utilizing the ReadItemAsync method, since I don't have the unique id value in this case?

```
        PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKeyBuilder()
        .Add(id) //pk
        .Add("user") //hpk
        .Build();
        ItemResponse<dynamic> readResponse = await container.ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(        
            partitionKey: new PartitionKey(id)
        );
```

Or is this something that can only be achieved by a SELECT statement?

22/08/2023 - Added after reading Balajis answer -

Here is the screenshot of the sample record that I want to retrieve -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sumchans, In first line you specified that **phoneNumber** as `partitionKey` but in the code snippet below you mentioned **id** as `partitionKey` in comment. So, I tried with both and below are my solutions.

Solution-1: **id** as `partitionKey`.

**Explanation:**

- The `id` variable contains the document ID of the specific document you want to retrieve.
- The `ReadItemAsync` function uses this ID as the value for the partition key and the document ID.
- `PartitionKeyBuilder` is used to create "id" as a **partition key** and "user" as the **hierarchical partition key**.
- The created `partitionKey` and the `document id` are passed as parameters when the `ReadItemAsync` method is called.
- Based on the provided partition key and ID, this function retrieves the specified document.

**Code I have tried with:**

Below is the code with **Id** as `partitionKey`.

```cs
string connectionString = "*****";
string databaseId = "nhDb";
string containerId = "newCont";

CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(connectionString);
Container container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);

string id = "5"; 
try
{
    PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKeyBuilder()
       .Add(id) // pk (id)
       .Add("user") // hpk (hierarchical partition key)
       .Build();

    ItemResponse<dynamic> readResponse = await container.ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(
    partitionKey: partitionKey,
    id: id
    );

    if (readResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
       dynamic item = readResponse.Resource;
       Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved item: {item}");
     }
}
catch (CosmosException ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}
```

**Input:**
[image]

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Solution-2: **phoneNumber** as `partitionKey`.

**Explanation:**

- The phone number you want to utilize as part of the **partition key** is contained in `phoneNumber`.
- **id** contains the document ID for the particular document you want to retrieve.
- `PartitionKeyBuilder` is used to create "phoneNumber" as a **partition key** and "user" as the **hierarchical partition key**.
- The created `partitionKey` and the `document id`  are passed as arguments when the `ReadItemAsync` function is invoked.
- Based on the provided partition key and ID, this function retrieves the specified document.

**Code I have tried with:**

Below is the code with **phoneNumber** as `partitionKey`.

```cs
string connectionString = "*****";
string databaseId = "hDb";
string containerId = "newCont";

CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(connectionString);
Container container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);

string phoneNumber = "14332111111"; 
string id = "5"; 
try
{
    PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKeyBuilder()
      .Add(phoneNumber) // pk (phone number)
      .Add("user") // hpk (hierarchical partition key)
      .Build();

    ItemResponse<dynamic> readResponse = await container.ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(
         partitionKey: partitionKey,
         id: id
    );

    if (readResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
       dynamic item = readResponse.Resource;
       Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved item: {item}");
    }
}
catch (CosmosException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}
```

**Input:**
[image]

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Balaji for the detailed explanation. In my case solution two is the one that I will be looking at. Every single document in my container would have an unique id value, the the partitionKey would be the phoneNumber and Hierarchical Partition Key would be "user". Here the problem I am having is when querying, what I will be having as parameters for the ReadItemAsync method would be just the partitionKey & the Hierarchical partition key for which I am expecting only a single document to be returned. How can I read a point read if I cant provide an Id value for the ReadItemAsync method?

Comment: @Sumchans, Referring to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.readitemasync?view=azure-dotnet). "**id**" Is mandatory to pass as a parameter in `ReadItemAsync` method. We can achieve expected output by taking "id" as partition key and "user" as hierarchical partition key when we give same values for both "id" and "phoneNumber".